# firefox makes paperclip store special characters as questionmarks

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

When I upload a file called 'åäöÅÄÖ.jpg' using Firefox it stores it as 'a?a?o?A?A?O?.jpg'

Using Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorerit works fine.

When I watch the Rails console the query for inserting the file name looks ok:

```
BlogHeader Update (0.4ms)   UPDATE 'blog_headers' 
  SET 'large_file_name' = 'åäöÅÄÖ.jpg', 
  'updated_at' = '2012-10-19 14:13:36' WHERE 'id' = 14`
```

Obviously an encoding issue, but I can't seem to track down where along the line it breaks. Any ideas? Using Rails 2.3.11 and Paperclip 2.8.0.

**Edit:**
Another way of solving this would be to rename the filename once the file is uploaded (using a regex to remove all non a-z chars for example). I've been looking at interpolation in Paperclip, but since that applies to already uploaded files it breaks them as well.

Comment: Does the form tag where you submit the uploaded file contain: <form accept-charset="UTF-8">?

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously an encoding issue, seems that firefox is not forcing utf8 for you, you can try putting this in the view:

```
# encoding utf-8
```

and

```
if defined? Encoding 
  Encoding.default_internal = 'UTF-8'
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

in your `environment.rb`

This could be a problem with your mysql encoding as well, perhaps the mysql connector is not setting encoding properly.  Try the above.

Comment: I added the latter part without any change to environment.rb. How exactly do you mean I should set the encoding variable in the view?

Comment: in the view, literally put `# encoding utf-8` as the first line, you can also try enforcing it by using utf-8 characters in the query string, often ?utf8=✓ is added to force utf8 in browsers

Comment: `# encoding utf-8` is only needed in the page if you are going to have Unicode literal directly in the source code, it isn't necessary to manipulate strings which have Unicode in it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest forcing encoding on your string, e.g. if the file name is in the variable called file_name:

```
file_name = file_name.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, but encoding using Iconv for example using paperclip's interpolation doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have one more option. Try to changet database.yml file. Like this

```
   development:
     adapter: mysql
     encoding: utf8
     database: depot1_dev
     pool: 5
     username: root
     password: 
     host: localhost
     ...
```

I hope it may be work

Comment: sorry, we have the encoding set to utf8 in the database.yml file already.